# Two sentences without conjunction?

Tags: grammar, free-relative-clauses

Is there any grammar mistake in this sentence?

#### " What's even worse, I slept right through my stop! "

I think this sentence is incorrect because two sentences are connected without any conjunction.

- If this sentence is correct, why?
- If this sentence is incorrect, how to make it correct?

Comment: @Damkerng T. What even worse was **that** I slept right through my stop!   <-- Is this better?

Comment: Of course. I usually drop that *that*. Bad habit. Bad habit. :)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Getting rid of *that* seems okay to me, but **what even worse* is ungrammatical.  (A typo, I imagine?)

Comment: @snailboat Perhaps I should stick with *What's even worse is that I slept through my stop!* (I confused myself by trying to swap words around.) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely acceptable in speech and informal writing, and possibly acceptable in all but the most pompously formal writing.

A coordinating conjunction won’t work here: the first piece, *What’s even worse*, is not a sentence but a “free relative clause”, a construction which almost always acts as a noun phrase.

There are three ways of understanding this sentence:

- *What’s even worse* acts as the subject of a sentence in which the copula and the complementizer *that* have have been omitted.

  > What’s even worse [**is that**] I slept right through my stop.
- *What’s even worse* is a bare NP announcing a topic, which is then defined by the subsequent clause. You could repoint it to express this reading:

  > What’s even worse: I slept right through my stop.
- *What’s even worse* acts not as an NP but as a sentential adverbial, similar to *Furthermore* or *Moreover*. The same thought could be expressed by the bare adverb *Worse*:

  > Worse, I slept right through my stop.

It doesn’t really matter how you parse it. It’s just an idiomatic way of saying that what happened next was even worse than what went before.

Comment: Other terms found in literature for "fee relative" are: fused relative (construction), headless relative clause, and headless relative clause