# Why these two sentences can connect without conjunction?

Tags: sentence-structure

I saw a sentence in an essay:

> Health inequalities, for example, are central to the campaigning work of a number of organisations who lobby for an individual system of care that is divorced from psychiatric frameworks, the project ‘Bare Bars’ campaigns against carceral injustices, while the importance of media representation fuels the work of Trans Media Watch, which collaborates with cultural industries to bring about more positive representations of trans* people across the UK media.

I don't know why it can use a comma before **"the project ‘Bare Bars’ campaigns against carceral injustices"** to connect the two sub-sentences without any conjunction?

I have read [Two sentences without conjunction?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14810/two-sentences-without-conjunction), but it seems that my case is not the same as the case asked in that post.

Comment: They can't. This is a run-on sentence, and probably a mistake.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman already said, it is probably a mistake. It should start as a new sentence altogether, or can be separated using semi-colon.